# Is a tablespoon of vinegar and a cloth adequate to clean tiles with compiled soap, dirt residue?

Tags: bathroom, floor, cleaning, ceramic-tile, product-recommendation

What is a good product that can effectively clean tiles without damaging them?
The type of tiles are floor tiles I think are ceramic based on [this](https://gemmill.com.au/blog/11-different-types-of-tile-flooring/) and are not shiny.
I would like to clean them of residues of soap and dust.
I have tried to clean them with water and a tablespoon of vinegar and rub with a cloth but seems to require quite an effort and may be there is a better way.

Comment: Hey Jim, welcome to the site.  We're going to need more details to your question.  Specifically what type of tiles, what are you cleaning off of them, what have you tried already, etc.  Also, the way your question is phrased is more like a shopping "what's the best" question, so try to focus on a particular problem.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Is the update better?

Comment: Yea, that’s better. Pictures are awesome and easy to post with a smartphone, but understandable if not possible.

Comment: CLR would be a product I would try. Test in an inconspicuous spot first.

Comment: @Kris: What is CLR?

Comment: @Jim  a cleaning product for removing Calcium Lime and Rust among other things. Very effective on soap scum too.  http://www.clrclean.com.au/

Comment: @JPhi1618: Do you think if I add some photo I might get answer(s)?

Comment: It certainly would help.  There are just so many types of tiles and stains.   Hard to give good general advice.

Comment: @Kris: How would I use it in a tile? Seems quite strong

Comment: @Jim  https://clrbrands.com/en-US/Products/CLR-Household/CLR-Bath-Kitchen-Cleaner.   This link will answer most questions and gives usage instructions

Answer (score 2):

I guess we can pick up cleaning stuff here.

I like borax powder for scrubbing.  20 Mule Team borax is a brand in the US and it is cheap.  You should be able to get it in a big cardboard box.  It is a light abrasive but will not scratch the tile.  I use plenty and it does not have chlorine or acid in it that could cause trouble.  Mostly I like that it is cheap and it works.

If you want stronger scrubs you could buy a purpose-made scrubbing powder.  Comet is one with chlorine that I think is available worldwide.  Barkeeps Friend and Zud have oxalic acid and they work.

You could try scrubbing with an abrasive pad.  ScotchBrite is made of hard green plastic fibers.  They will not scratch the tile like a steel wool pad could and they cut thru gunk well.

Comment: How much do you use and how? Do you use very small amount of water?

Comment: Yes small amount of water or it will dissolve all the borax.  Wet the tiles then dust them with a few spoonfuls of borax.  When you scrub it will get to be a paste.

Comment: Wet the tiles, throw borax and wait a few mins or immediately start scrubbing?

Comment: Start scrubbing immediately.  I must say this is far and away the most I have ever written on cleaning up scum!

Comment: Yes but your advice saves the day!!!!! For how long do I scrub? How do I know it stayed too long?