# How can I remove heavy soap scum on a glass shower door?

Tags: bathroom, shower, cleaning, glass

I have a glass door with very heavy soap scum.

I used a product that is for cleaning the bathroom and tiles, but didn't help that much. Either the scum is too much or the product is not good enough.
I had tried vinegar but that didn't help either or maybe I didn't do a great job applying it.

Is there an effective process for removing heavy soap scum residue on shower doors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Plastic putty knife.**

[image: plastic putty knife]

[source](https://www.grainger.com/product/1DBA1?ef_id=Cj0KCQjw_8mHBhClARIsABfFgpirtY3TyOJfbJZltWX74L1QirIJMVvixOdAnu_XCqEvvh5JVJUzMXMaAuY8EALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!496359971677!!!g!439063557338!&gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_8mHBhClARIsABfFgpirtY3TyOJfbJZltWX74L1QirIJMVvixOdAnu_XCqEvvh5JVJUzMXMaAuY8EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

This is the best thing for thick scum on a scratchable surface.  And the price is right too - you can get one for less than $1.  Or if you are in Duluth, bust out your windshield ice scraper and give it some off-season work.  You will need to apply some grease of the elbow variety.

You can leave the scraper in the shower and get after it again when you notice it building up again.

Comment: Is it to use directly on dry glass surface or wet? Is this similar to what you have in mind? https://www.amazon.com/s?k=plastic+putty+knife&sprefix=Plastic+putty+knife%2Caps%2C268 I am not in US

Comment: I think I have razor scrapers for the kitchen top. Would that also work? Or would it scratch the glass?

Comment: Razor would work great but you would need to be careful.  Nice and slow just like shaving your face.   The good thing about the plastic putty knife or windshield ice scraper is you can just go wild and you wont hurt the glass.

Comment: both the plastic knife and the razor in a dry surface?

Comment: @jim - I think it would work better wet.  The deposits might soften.   If we assume the scum is calcium and magnesium salts of soap, then something hydrophobic like oil could soften them even better than water - the soap molecule is hydrophobic and will pull in the oil.  I would hate to buy oil just for this because I am cheap.  I would use some vegetable oil that I have and rub it onto the scum and let it sit overnight.   I predict it will then come right off with either kind of scraper.  Come back and post how it works!

Comment: So if I understand correctly the process would be: apply oil (salad oil that we eat would do right?) on the area, let it stay overnight. Then start scrapping it.  I assume after the scrapping pass with soap and rinse with water?

Comment: That sounds good.  Yes: soap and water to finish and get off the oil.

Comment: Ok, so I applied that in a small surface using the razor for electric stoves and the area got clean! Thanks a lot! I have the following questions: 1) How much oil should I be using in general? I.e. how do I know too much/too less? 2) Should I scrub in one direction only at a time? Or both vertical horizontal are fine? 3) The process to do it to the whole area will be very time consuming. a) would buying that putty knife help move faster? b) now that the reason of the soil is known, is there some other faster/radical way with less effort?

Comment: 1.  Just enough oil to "wet" it.  Extra will run off.  2.   For this kind of scraping I scrape one direction.  Especially with the razor.   3.  It is hard to beat a razor for something like this.  4.  Once scum is gone hang a squeegee in shower and squeegee it off after each shower.  The scum will not build up and you wont have to do this again.  But you do now.

Comment: I did in both vertical and horizontal direction in that small area because after I finished with the vertical one, there were still some harder spots that the horizontal scrub removed them. Would that mean I didn't use enough oil?

Comment: The squeege is after the clean up. I was wondering now that we have verified the type of scum, is there a faster approach e.g. with a specific chemical?

Comment: I also have 2 final questions for you: 1) I have heard of some portable steamer, is that of any use especially for these kind of cases? 2) Besides edible oil, what other kind of oil could we use? I'd like to know and compare the prices

Comment: Hi Jim.  The cleaning products that best cut soap scum are strong bases.  The strongest I keep in the house is automatic dishwasher gel which is sodium carbonate.  You can get lye and stronger bases,  Please be very careful with these splashing them around vertical surfaces!  Getting them to stick will be tricky.  The oil and scrape is safe and works fine.  As re oil you can use any oil.  I said vegetable oil because I figured you had it but mineral oil would be fine if it is cheaper.  Motor oil seems like a mess but that would probably work too.

Comment: That dishwasher gel, is it safe only for specific type of surfaces? Otherwise what do you mean by `be very careful with these splashing them around vertical surfaces`? Only that they might just drip down? But no other damage?

Comment: What about steamers? Are they any good? I could buy if they are useful

Comment: Also what do you use to place the oil on the surface. I tried cotton and it absorbed a lot of oil. Also with a paper towel, lot of it was absorbed. The surface is vertical so a (large) portion of it is absorbed by the time I apply it. What material is better for this case?

Comment: Caustic liquids can get on your skin and burn you and get in your eye and blind you.  You can buy terribly corrosive liquids at the store.  Putting something like that on a wall will get it all over and all over you.  That stuff is DANGEROUS!  Re steamer: if hot water could get it off it would not be in the shower.  Dont waste your money.    Re salad oil: I would use my bare hand to apply it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the tips! Your advice was a saver! This approach with the oil and the cutter/razor to what other surfaces can I apply it? Would it work e.g. with soap scum on tiles or would the razor damaze the tiles?

Comment: You could try it.  I dont think it will damage tiles.  You might be able to do better on tiles with a scouring powder of some kind because you dont need to worry as much about scratching.  I have had luck with borax powder but there are many powders for this on the market.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://www.amazon.com/MILLIARD-Borax-Powder-Multi-Purpose-Cleaner/dp/B00HLROBQ4 and how do you use it exactly? Is it for the soap scum removal and limestone as well?

Comment: I had an old question on this, if you have time for some tips it would be highly appreciated for what's that worth: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/179669/is-a-tablespoon-of-vinegar-and-a-cloth-adequate-to-clean-tiles-with-compiled-soa

Answer (score 1):

Well DIY recipes can be anything up to powerful hazardous chemicals, so I would not discount them entirely.  Different chemicals will work better depending on your water and what has built up.  Could be lime, calcium or soap scum.

Personally, on hard surfaces I'm partial to comet with safety goggles and a spinny brush, but for softer surfaces with grime and soap scum, you could try scrubbin' bubbles.  CLR may be useful for Calcium and Lime as well.  Similar products may have different brands where you live.  You may need to use a bit of trial and error and it wouldn't hurt to ask local friends what works for them.  Some chemicals work wonders if you spray, walk away for an hour, then spray again and scrub.  Others seem to gain little.  Can't hurt to give a melamine sponge(magic eraser) a shot, and toothpaste makes an excellent soft abrasive in some cases too.

Don't underestimate the value of scrubbing with a brush, it has very good abrasion for how soft it is on surfaces.  Don't underestimate the value of putting a brush on a drill, but wear safety goggles so you don't blind yourself with chemical.

Amounts to figuring out what it is well enough to either dissolve it or abrade it without marring the surface below.  Be cautious working on plastics.

Comment: What is CLR? Also what kind of brush are you suggesting?

Comment: What googles and brush are you using?

Comment: @Jim CLR is a cleaning product. It's called that because it gets rid of calcium, lime, and rust, but searching "CLR cleaner" should bring it up. Any safety goggles which protect your eyes from liquids splashing into them should work.

Comment: I use standard jobsite safety goggles, but swim goggles would be fine as you're not trying to stop projectiles.  By brushes, I mean plastic bristled scrub brushes, and if you'd like to use one with a drill, I purchase round "soap dispensing scrub brush"es with longish bristles.  I bash off the "container" part, leaving only a round brush, and drill out the center soap dispensing hole and put a bolt in so I can chuck it into a drill.  Think about how you mount the bolt so you don't end up with it sticking out and scratching what you're trying to brush.

Comment: Next time I see my homemade spinny brush I'll take a picture and add it to this post.  It's actually the most absurdly useful cleaning tool for the cost of a $5 brush and a $1 bolt if you own a drill.  Sometimes I operate the drill inside a bag if I'm worried about getting chemicals in the guts.  I couldn't find already made versions where I live, but it's called a "drill brush" and I may not have needed to make my own based on my google search.  Canadian tire has a nice 3pc set for $20 and Aliexpress a 5 piece set for $2.82.

Comment: @KH: Do you mean something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Amazer-Bathroom-Comfortable-Odourless-Bristles/dp/B06Y5JW8NY/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=plastic+bristle+scrub+brushes&qid=1626689628&sr=8-3-spons&psc=1

Comment: @Jim [More something like this](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/mastercraft-drill-brush-set-3pc-0542096p.0542096.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxdSHBhCdARIsAG6zhlU8KY5mGHfXNIRcjKhQGR6VSZL6f3vrfMQmAyEbBhZyNFKo3FL38LIaApHWEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#store=326)

Answer (score 1):

Try glass stovetop cleaner and scrubbing pads. They're intended for getting tough residue off glass without harming it, which is exactly the same problem here, and I often use it on my shower doors. It takes a lot of elbow grease, but it will get them sparkling clean. I find it works better if you mist a bit of water onto the door before scrubbing, and it's definitely easier if you take the doors down (I lay them on top of some thick towels so the glass is cushioned).

[Here's the particular brand I use](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Weiman-Products-Complete-Cook-Top-Cleaning-Kit-with-10-oz-Cream/1002892758) and generally see for sale near me, but I imagine anything marketed for this purpose should work.

I've also heard from several people that a steam cleaner works very well, but I've never personally tried it.

Comment: Aren't the scrubbing pads too rough?

Comment: @Jim no, they're designed for glass.

Comment: Which scrubbing pads are designed for glass? If I google that, I see the ones we use for pots, which I think are very hard for glass

Comment: @Jim I gave a link to an example brand. That kit includes scrubbing pads.

Comment: You can use a paper towel instead, it will just take more scrubbing.